# Is there a canonical way of comparing/changing one/two records in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to compare two records in haskell, without defining each change in the datatype of the record with and each function  of 2 datas for all of the elements of the record over and over.

I read about lens, but I could not find an example for that,
and do not know where begin to read in the documentation.

Example, not working:

```hs
data TheState = TheState { number :: Int,
                           truth  :: Bool
                         }

initState = TheState 77 True

-- not working, example:
stateMaybe = fmap Just initState
--  result should be:
--  ANewStateType{ number = Just 77, truth = Just True}
```

The same way, I want to compare the 2 states:

```hs
state2 = TheState 78 True
-- not working, example
stateMaybe2 = someNewCompare initState state2
-- result should be:
-- ANewStateType{ number = Just 78, truth = Nothing}
```

Comment: I can certainly answer part of your question: `fmap Just initState` doesn’t work because (a) your fields are defined to be of type `Int` and `Bool`, so you can’t change them to `Maybe Int` and `Maybe Bool`, and (b) `TheState` isn’t a functor — a functor requires a type variable to map over so you can change the type, and you haven’t given `TheState` any type variable. As for the rest of your question, I have no idea how you would do this, although you may be interested in [Higher-Kinded Data](http://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/higher-kinded-data/).

Comment: I sort of understand what you want with `stateMaybe`. But I'm completely lost about what logic `someNewCompare` should have in it to decide that `someNewCompare (TheState 77 True) (TheState 78 True) = ANewStateType (Just 78) Nothing`.

Comment: @bradrn: Yes, that's a part of the answer I need: How to make a Functor out of a record. For that I have an answer: apply the function to all of the items of the record. 
But that must keep the same datatypes :-( . Perhaps i want to make the record an applicative, then the items must become functions.

Comment: @bradrn: 
Shortly said: I want to use the record as an heterogenous container / hashmap, where the names determine the values-types.

Comment: @Daniel: someNewCompare shall be a diff of the records: ```diff :: Eq a=> a -> a -> Maybe a  
diff a b = case a==b of
     True  -> Nothing
     False -> Just b```

In```someNewCompare``` this shall be done for each element of the records.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned in comments, it's most likely easier to create a different record to hold the `Maybe` version of the fields and do the manual conversion. However there is a way to get the functor like mapping over your fields in a more automated way.

It's probably more involved than what you would want but it's possible to achieve using a pattern called **Higher Kinded Data** (**HKD**) and a library called [`barbies`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies).

Here is a amazing blog post on the subject: https://chrispenner.ca/posts/hkd-options

And here is my attempt at using **HKD** on your specific example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts   #-}

-- base
import           Data.Functor.Identity
import           GHC.Generics          (Generic)

-- barbie
import           Data.Barbie

type TheState = TheState_ Identity

data TheState_ f = TheState
  { number :: f Int
  , truth  :: f Bool
  } deriving (Generic, FunctorB)

initState :: TheState
initState = TheState (pure 77) (pure True)

stateMaybe :: TheState_ Maybe
stateMaybe = bmap (Just . runIdentity) initState
```

What is happening here, is that we are wrapping every field of the record in a custom `f`. We now get to choose what to parameterise `TheState` with in order to wrap every field. A *normal* record now has all of its fields wrapped in `Identity`. But you can have other versions of the record easily available as well. The `bmap` function let's you map your transformation from one type of `TheState_` to another.

Honestly, the blog post will do a much better job at explaining this than I would. I find the subject very interesting, but I am still very new to it myself.

Hope this helped! :-)

Answer (score 0):

> How to make a Functor out of a record. For that I have an answer: apply the function to > all of the items of the record.
>
> I want to use the record as an heterogenous container / hashmap, where
> the names determine the values-types

While there's no "easy", direct way of doing this, it can be accomplished with several existing libraries.

This answer uses [red-black-record](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record) library, which is itself built over the anonymous products of [sop-core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core). "sop-core" allows each field in a product to be wrapped in a functor like `Maybe` and provides functions to manipulate fields uniformly. "red-black-record" inherits this, adding named fields and conversions from normal records.

To make `TheState` compatible with "red-black-record", we need to do the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables,
             DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass,
             TypeApplications #-}

import GHC.Generics 
import Data.SOP 
import Data.SOP.NP (NP,cliftA2_NP) -- anonymous n-ary products
import Data.RBR (Record, -- generalized record type with fields wrapped in functors
                 I(..),  -- an identity functor for "simple" cases
                 Productlike, -- relates a map of types to its flattened list of types
                 ToRecord, toRecord, -- convert a normal record to its generalized form 
                 RecordCode, -- returns the map of types correspoding to a normal record
                 toNP, fromNP, -- convert generalized record to and from n-ary product
                 getField) -- access field from generalized record using TypeApplication

data TheState = TheState { number :: Int,
                           truth  :: Bool
                         } deriving (Generic,ToRecord)
```

We auto-derive the [`Generic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) instance that allows other code to introspect the structure of the datatype. This is needed by [`ToRecord`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.4.0/docs/Data-RBR.html#t:ToRecord), that allows conversion of normal records into their ["generalized forms"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.4.0/docs/Data-RBR.html#t:Record).

Now consider the following function:

```
compareRecords :: forall r flat. (ToRecord r, 
                                  Productlike '[] (RecordCode r) flat, 
                                  All Eq flat) 
               => r 
               -> r 
               -> Record Maybe (RecordCode r)
compareRecords state1 state2 = 
    let mapIIM :: forall a. Eq a => I a -> I a -> Maybe a
        mapIIM (I val1) (I val2) = if val1 /= val2 then Just val2
                                                   else Nothing
        resultNP :: NP Maybe flat
        resultNP = cliftA2_NP (Proxy @Eq) 
                              mapIIM 
                              (toNP (toRecord state1)) 
                              (toNP (toRecord state2)) 
     in fromNP resultNP
```

It compares two records whatsoever that have `ToRecord r` instances, and also a corresponding flattened list of types that all have `Eq` instances (the `Productlike '[] (RecordCode r) flat` and `All Eq flat` constraints).

First it converts the initial record arguments to their generalized forms with [`toRecord`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.4.0/docs/Data-RBR.html#v:toRecord). These generalized forms are parameterized with an identity functor [`I`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.4.0/docs/Data-RBR.html#t:I) because they come from "pure" values and there aren't any effects are play, yet.

The generalized record forms are in turn converted to n-ary products with [`toNP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.4.0/docs/Data-RBR.html#v:toNP).

Then we can use the [`cliftA2_NP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html#v:cliftA2_NP) function from "sop-core" to compare accross all fields using their respective `Eq` instances. The function requires specifying the `Eq` constraint using a [`Proxy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html).

The only thing left to do is reconstructing a generalized record (this one parameterized by `Maybe`) using [`fromNP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.4.0/docs/Data-RBR.html#v:fromNP).

An example of use:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let comparison = compareRecords (TheState 0 False) (TheState 0 True)
    print (getField @"number" comparison)
    print (getField @"truth" comparison)
```

[`getField`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.4.0/docs/Data-RBR.html#v:getField) is used to extract values from generalized records. The field name is given as a [`Symbol`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Symbol) by way of [`-XTypeApplications`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=typeapplications#extension-TypeApplications).

Comment: See also "generics-sop" as an alternative to "red-black-record" http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop